# AllowAnonymous attribute being ignored in MVC4 with ClaimsAuthorizationManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, wif, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to use a custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager based on the excellent work from Dominic Baier within a new MVC4 application which is still very much based on the out-of-box Internet template and when I configure it it seems to want to authorize everything and ignores the [AllowAnonymous] attribute.

Looking at the stack trace is seems that the ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 triggers the AuthorizationManager code.

[image: IIS7.5 Detailed Error]

I'm feel like it's either a configuration problem with my web.config (See below) or I need some additional logic in my AuthorizationManager not to perform the check at that time.

My completeness here is the Controller snippet:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
```

The system.web section :

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authorization>
    <!--<deny users="?" />-->
  </authorization>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="simple">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<httpModules>
  <!--WIF 4.5 modules -->
  <!--Not needed here for IIS >= 7 -->
  <!--<add name="ClaimsAuthorizationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.ClaimsAuthorizationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>-->
</httpModules>
```

The system.webServer section :

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="RoleManager" />
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />

    <!--WIF 4.5 modules -->
    <add name="ClaimsAuthorizationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.ClaimsAuthorizationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <add name="ClaimsTransformationModule" type="HillIntl.MyLCM.Security.ClaimsTransformationHttpModule" />

    <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

The identity model section :

```
<!--WIF 4.5 s.im section-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the claims authZ module, it is indeed triggered on every request. You need a custom [Authorize] attribute for MVC4 to play nice with claims authorization.

Similar to this: http://leastprivilege.com/2012/06/22/authorization-in-asp-net-web-api/